# React: memo does not work - OnClick button cause re render

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

In this example I'm using memo to prevent component re renderning, however, it gets re rendered on every button click even item props does not change. According to react documentation, component with memo won't re render only if props have been changed.

```
import React, { memo, useContext } from "react";
import { BasketContext } from "./Context";

const ItemCard = React.memo(({ item }) => {
  const [basket, setBasket] = useContext(BasketContext);
  function addItem() {
    const index = basket.findIndex((v) => v.id === item.id);
    if (index >= 0) {
      const data = [...basket];
      data[index].qte++;
      setBasket(data);
    } else {
      const newItem = Object.assign({}, item);
      newItem.qte = 1;
      setBasket(basket.concat([newItem]));
    }
  }

  return (
    <div className="card">
      <div className="card-body">
        <h5 className="card-title">{item.title}</h5>
        <button className="btn btn-primary" onClick={addItem}>
          Add to cart
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
});

export default ItemCard;
```

Answer (score 0):

But when you click on the Button you are making the call to `setBasket` .If i am not wrong setBasket is the state updater function provided by you to update the state from `useContext` .

The component not only will re-render when the `props` change it will also re-render for `state` change as well . Whenever your `value` in the context provider changes . All the components which is subscribed to that context will re-render

So wrapping the component with `React.memo` won't prevent the re-render in this case.

Comment: What's the solution ?